# Flash Scope from Grails alternative for Spring MVC

Tags: spring, grails, scope

I'm interested to know if there is a built in object in Spring MVC that has properties like [Flash](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Controller+Scopes) for Grails?

Any info would be useful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is already a ticket in the bugtracker:

https://issues.springsource.org/browse/MOD-458